# Queuing models in R

Tags: r, simulation

At a post office, customers enter a single line waiting to be served by any one of two clerks.  Every minute there is a 60% chance that a new customer arrives.  If there is no one in line and a server is free, the customer does not wait to be served.  When a customer is being served there is a 25% chance every minute that they complete their business and leave.  When the clerk is free he will take the next customer in line, in the order that they arrived.  Every minute, there is a 5% chance that a person standing in line will give up and leave.  The post office is always open (24/7/365).

a) What is the average amount of time a customer spends in the post office (including those not served)?
b) What percentage of customers leave without being served?
c) What percentage of time are the clerks idle?

Comment: I understand little bit logic about this problem. First I have to create n, if the probability more than .6 then 1 else 0. But I don't know how to calculate service time and service rate.

Comment: This sure smells like a homework assignment.  Are you expecting SO to do your homework for you?

Comment: Its not homework. I need some help, how to proceed with it.